# How do you apply vibrato to a chord?

Tags: guitar, classical-music, vibrato

I am practicing vibrato, classical guitar vibrato like rolling finger tips on the fretboard.

One note vibrato is ok but a chord vibrato looks quite ugly.
Not enough rolling finger tips are done.

Is there a specific part of a hand that needs to be more relaxed?

I am forcing my left hand move left and right along the fretboard and the guitar rocks left and right also needlessly, which professional players' guitars don't seem to do.

Answer (score 4):

It definitely shouldn't feel like "forcing" the hand left and right. They key is placing the fingers precisely on the fretboard, with just enough force for the notes to sound clear, and then gently moving the hand with increasing amplitude. Note, in classical music, vibrato is typically a subtle effect and you don't need a great amplitude.

Vibrato is actually a good way to practice difficult chords, as it enforces both precision and relaxation.

> Is there a specific part of a hand that needs to be more relaxed?

In general, not only for vibrato, you want to avoid using too much force with your fingers and avoid pressing the fingers against the thumb. The role of thumb is to stabilize the hand. Instead, use your arm to press the hand against the fretboard - but again, only as much as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Classical guitar vibrato comes from the *elbow*, nowhere else. You should already be very aware of your elbow and already moving it as you fret in order to keep the most relaxed hand position. If you’re not already using your elbow to support your hand position then I’m afraid you have a lot of study and practice on technique ahead of you.

If you are already elbow aware then when you’ve fretted a note or chord and want vibrato, just imagine you’re going to move up the fretboard and then down the fretboard and move your elbow accordingly in preparation. With a relaxed elbow movement and proper hand and thumb position, the vibrato should feel totally relaxed and natural. Your elbow doesn’t know or care if you’re holding down a single note or a chord, so it feels the same either way.